# gksu is not availabe in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: flash, chromium, gksu

I have recently downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 from its site and updated it. I was going to install peperflash in chromium browser but it asks for gksu.

I have run

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

but it says the package is unavailable. How can I install gksu?

Comment: You have run `sudo apt-get update` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure that universe is included.  Or open software sources, and make sure of that.

[image]

Once done, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gksu
```